# Django creating non-auth single use access tokens

Tags: python, django

I'm creating an app where in users will be able to add reviews to specific places.

I'm creating a system in which each review will be held when it is submitted, and an email will be sent to site managers who'll be able to approve or reject the review by clicking on two distinct links.

These links will be mapped to a particular Django view function, which will receive the id of particular review being approved/rejected, and an access token to ensure the authenticity of link.

Everywhere I've search, I can only find "Auth tokens" for signing in users, which is not what I want in this case.

One way I've thought of is to create a hash of review and commend id, store a field in database about whether this token has been accessed or not. But this solution doesn't seem very "DRY".

Any way of generating these tokens?

Comment: Since the "links" are altering state on the server, you should actually be sending POST requests.  You can use Django's XSRF token mechanism to secure them.

Comment: The method you suggested sounds ok to me except POST vs GET issue @SvenMarnach pointed out. Where is the part you _repeat_ yourself, hence not being DRY?

Comment: @SvenMarnach yeah i agree with the POST request. But how can I do a post request through an email link? Or should the link point towards a page which has the relevant form and then it can do a POST request, right?

Comment: @Selcuk By "dry" i meant that maybe Django already has some kind of functionality for tackling this, so therefore I should use that

Comment: @KartikAnand You can't POST from an email, but you can ask for a reconfirmation in the linked page and do the actual POST there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature included with Django which you can use for this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signing/

If I understood your use case correctly you can use the object id as the value to sign, then make a view which accepts the signed value as an arg, from which it can derive the id while ensuring that the link was authentic.

eg

```
from django.core import signing
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


signer = Signer()


def make_review_links(review_id):
    # a function to generate the links you can use in the email template
    signed = signer.sign(str(review_id))
    approve_link = reverse('approve_review', args=[review_id])
    reject_link = reverse('reject_review', args=[review_id])
    return approve_link, reject_link


def approve_review(request, signed):
    try:
        review_id = signer.unsign(value)
    except signing.BadSignature:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Invalid link")
    review = get_object_or_404(Review, pk=review_id)
    # approval code here
```

I do agree with the commenters on your question though, as a actions that change data on the server these should be POST requests. The pattern would be the same as above, but instead of the view getting `signed` value from a url arg you'd get it from `request.POST`. You may even want to use a Form.

Obviously, to do a POST from an email is only possible with an HTML email. To support text emails you should link to an intermediary page (passing the signed value) that presents a form with Approve/Reject buttons, which should POST the signed value as hidden field to a view as above.